# Using static Sprite array in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

What is the best way to approach using Static sprite arrays in Unity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use static objects to store any assets. This is bad practice as you have no control over the lifetime of static objects.

In Unity you should use [ScriptableObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html) and access it (if you want static access you can use [Singleton Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern))

```csharp
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "SpriteArrays", menuName = "ScriptableObjects/SpriteArrays", order = 1)]
class SpriteArrays : ScriptableObject
{
    public Sprite[] Sprites;
}
```

Now you can access a single point of reference for all of your classes that need to use the same sprites, that you can edit from the inspector (Create this asset using menu "Assets/Create/ScriptableObjects/SpriteArrays").

[image: ScriptableObject]

You can use this instance as Prefab or any other asset, and you can reference it from script.

```
public SpriteArrays Sprites;

public void Start()
{
    // Use sprites that you attached via Inspector to Sprites field
}
```

For more further reading you should also see [AssetBundles](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html) and [Addressables](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.addressables@1.16/manual/index.html)

Comment: That's a nice answer. I was not aware of addressables it'll change my way to handle assets. Thank you !

Comment: @D.B Your welcome! Please accept the answer as accepted if this answered your question :)
Edit: Didn't notice you are not OP, ups :P

Comment: I'm not the question author ;)

Comment: That is a great way to do things, thank you.